# Resolving interrupt-on-change mismatch conditions in a PIC16F877

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, assembly

I am using pic16f887 to quickly simulate encoder to later use it in a bigger project. reading signals from A and B encoder using interrupt on change for portb and the program was :

```
if(RBIF) 
{
  value++;
  UART_Write('b');
  __delay_ms(100);
  RBIF = 0;
}
```

and when I changed it to:

```
if(RBIF) 
{
  asm(" MOVF _PORTB" );  
  value++;
  UART_Write('b');
  __delay_ms(100);
  RBIF = 0;
}
```

and this This ends mismatch conditions!!
my question is what is the mismatch conditions and why loading w with portb ends that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know it's not recommended to use delays in interrupt, but that was just for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behavior of this microcontroller.  Please see the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41291D.pdf), page 47:

> For enabled interrupt-on-change pins, the present value is compared with the old value latched on the last read of PORTB to determine which bits have changed or mismatched the old value. The ‘mismatch’ outputs of the last read are OR’d together to set the PORTB Change Interrupt flag bit (RBIF) in the INTCON register.

Also:

> A mismatch condition will continue to set flag bit RBIF. Reading or writing PORTB will end the mismatch condition and allow flag bit RBIF to be cleared.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me If can get the bit which is mismatched from this?

Comment: @Catch.Me Not that I know of. You could copy the PORTB value during each interrupt service and compare it manually to the previous value.  By the way, good job figuring out the solution experimentally!

Comment: and in this T removed asm. line

Comment: @Catch.Me Great! I'm glad it's working out.

Comment: BEST REGARDS MAN